# Rabbi Medan on the prophecy of Yoshiyahu

Tags: isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, biblical-criticism

In [this essay](http://www.herzog.ac.il/vtc/tvunot/mega14_medan.pdf), pg. 64, note 38, with regards to the attempt to prove that there were actually two Yeshayahus, and subsequent attempts to counter that claim, Rabbi Yaakov Medan wrote:

> ונסתייעו בנבואת איש האלוהים לירבעם על יאשיהו שיחלל את העגל בבית אל (מלכ"א, י"ג), אירוע שהיה למעלה משלוש מאות שנה לאחר הנבואה. לעניות דעתנו סיוע זה ניתן להידחות ואכמ"ל.
>
> Translation: "and they [those that countered the claim] were assisted in this by the prophecy of the man of God to Yerov'am on Yoshiyahu who will destroy the calf in Beit El ([Melachim 1:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/I_Kings.13.1-5?lang=bi)), an event that took place over three hundred years after the prophecy. In our view, this proof can easily be disproven, but now is not the time to do so."

I was wondering how this piece of evidence for the ability of prophets to prophecise in great detail and far into the future could be disproven. I found a class by Rav Medan on the subject of the Two Yeshayahus, but a few minutes into the class he mentioned this and again said that this particular point can easily be disproven, but stated that that should be an entire class in itself and so there, too, he didn't expand on the issue. I was unable to find any class of his that discusses this particular issue (there might be one, but I don't know).

Does anyone have any idea what he could have meant by this statement?

Comment: I suppose the simple answer is that prophets can prophecise the future only if necessary for the present which this was. It seems it was meant to scare them. Why it should is a separate question. But which are not necessary for the present they cant or better put they dont.

Comment: @interested I'm sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: I thought it was quite simple what dont you understand.

Comment: @interested I don't understand how that answers the question. You seem to agree with what most defenders of the Yoshiyahu connection as evidence that prophets can prophecise, when needed, in great detail. Rav Medan says that this point can be disproven as evidence (though he himself believes there was only one Yeshayahu, but this particular point according to him is irrelevant). I'm asking what he meant about disproving this - how is this disproven, while maintaining at the same time that there's only one Yeshayahu?

Comment: It doesnt prove if they can prophesy for a present necessary purpose then they also can for no present purpose.